# Not receiving verification letter ADMOB

Tags: admob, adsense

i have made admob account in september 2016 and i have set my currency to AED (United Arab Emirates Dirhams)
after 1 month address verification notification starts appearing and it were showing me to wait 3-4 weeks to receive verification letter on mailing address so after waiting 1 month i have not received any letter so i have requested verification PIN again on 18 Nov 2016 then someone told me that verification PIN will be sent when i pass my payment threshold which is showing as AED 350 in my currency, so today on 02/01/2017 i have passed payment threshold, now i am getting another notification about adding payment method, so my question is that will i have to wait another 3-4 weeks to receive verification PIN or should i request new PIN ?
any reply will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have Choice..either to wait for 2-4 weeks or to request a new pin from Admob.Google Admob provides 3 pin requests maximum after that if you have'nt received any Pin then it will ask to upload your ID to verify your Address.after that you will be verified in 24 hours..